# Excel macro updating cells one by one is horribly slow

Tags: excel, vba

```
' Remove thousand separator from all numeric cells
For each cel in Selection
    if "#,##0" = cel.NumberFormat then _
        cel.NumberFormat = "0"
Next cel
```

It updates 400 cells per second and while it does, Excel is irresponsive. I suspect undo history. Is there a way to do this in some kind of undo transaction?

Comment: You can't undo the effect of running a macro, can you? So I don't think undo is to blame here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find and replace formatting in Excel. Here's the example from the Excel 2010 help (search for `ReplaceFormat`):

> The following example sets the search criteria to find cells containing Arial, Regular, Size 10 font, replaces their formats with Arial, Bold, Size 8 font, and then calls the Replace method, with the optional arguments of SearchFormat and ReplaceFormat set to True to actually make the changes.

```
Sub MakeBold()

' Establish search criteria.
With Application.FindFormat.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 10
End With

' Establish replacement criteria.
With Application.ReplaceFormat.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .FontStyle = "Bold"
    .Size = 8
End With

' Notify user.
With Application.ReplaceFormat.Font
    MsgBox .Name & "-" & .FontStyle & "-" & .Size & _
        " font is what the search criteria will replace cell formats with."
End With

' Make the replacements in the worksheet.
Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", _
    SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True

End Sub
```

You should be able to modify the example to make the formatting change you need.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the automatic recalculation of cells is the culprit behind almost all serious excel vba performance issues. To test if that holds true do it like this:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
' put your problematic code here
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

If this didn't help, another likely culprit is screenupdating (though the performance hit from this is much less severe). Try:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' put your problematic code here
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Hope this helps in your case as well.

Comment: +1, good points. For extra credit you can save the state of Application.Calculation in a variable and set it back to what it previously was. Be aware that if your code stops with any error while calculation is turned off, it'll stay that way for the whole of Excel - this could potentially lead to *very serious and expensive* mistakes if e.g. financial calculations are involved, so put something in place to catch this.